# New line without using \n in Python

Tags: python, unix, ubuntu, gcc, compiler-errors

In python, I'm trying to do something to compile c source codes easily, including a line like that ;

```
import os
os.system("gcc %s -o %s -ansi" %(filename, filename[:-3])
```

But it gives me the error ;

```
sh: 2: -o: not found
```

To check what is wrong I'm trying to do this ;

```
print("gcc %s -o %s -ansi" %(filename, filename[:-3]))
```

and it gives me that ;

```
gcc foo.c
 -o foo -ansi
```

My question is why it occurs  and what should I do to prevent it ?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Try using subprocess to make such calls

Comment: Use `filename.strip()`.

Answer (score 2):

os.system is depreciated and it's recommended to use subprocess instead.

Splitting the filename on "." will ensure it works correctly even if the file extension differ.

And if you're using Python 3 I suggest you use format.

```
import subprocess

filename = filename.strip()
subprocess.call('gcc {} -o {} -ansi'.format(filename,filename.split(".")[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to strip away the newline from `filename`:

```
import os
import subprocess

filename = filename.strip()
subprocess.call(['gcc', filename, '-o', os.path.splitext(filename)[0], '-ansi'])
```

Answer (score 1):

`filename[:-3]` will return the whole string apart from the last **3** characters. Evidently, your last 3 characters are `.c\n`, which is why you have a newline in your formatted string, because `filename` equates to `foo.c\n`.

To remedy this I suppose you have two choices:

1) remove the \n from the string with `filename.strip()` (recommended, especially if you use filename often for these purposes)

2) use `filename[:-1]` instead of `filename`

Comment: @OnurTırtır feel free to accept the answer you found most helpful, it'll help others who come to this question seeking an answer. :)